# jQuery Sortable: element moves to top on drag

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, materialize

I'm using jQuery UI Sortable to drag and drop select menus.
I'm using MaterializeCSS as well for the style.

When I drag some element more than once, it goes to the top while dragging, and I want to avoid that.

I know that others have asked the same question here, but none of the answers previously given have solved my problem.

I don't know if this has something to do with the container option:

```
container: 'parent'
```

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/06je0bs2/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the floats are causing the bottom elements to go outside of the container when you drag them, and adding `overflow: auto;` to the parent elements will fix that.

And looks like `top: 0` with `position: absolute` is causing the element to go really high on the page when you drag more than once, and adding `position: relative` to the parent will fix that.

https://jsfiddle.net/06je0bs2/4/

Comment: it works correctly!